# How to Set Session Timeout in Spring Boot/Spring Webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.0, and I've set

`server.reactive.session.timeout=10s`

in my application.properties. I'm using the @EnableWebFlux annotation, but the code in the EnableWebFluxConfiguration class is never run (verified with Debugger, and the fact that my sessions do not timeout after 10s). In the TRACE logs, I see

```
TRACE 279856 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.condition.OnBeanCondition        : Condition OnBeanCondition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxAutoConfiguration did not match due to @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurationSupport; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurationSupport' org.springframework.web.reactive.config.DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration
```

This is the bean that is not getting created

```
@Bean
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = WebHttpHandlerBuilder.WEB_SESSION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME)
        public WebSessionManager webSessionManager(ObjectProvider<WebSessionIdResolver> webSessionIdResolver) {
            DefaultWebSessionManager webSessionManager = new DefaultWebSessionManager();
            Duration timeout = this.serverProperties.getReactive().getSession().getTimeout();
            webSessionManager.setSessionStore(new MaxIdleTimeInMemoryWebSessionStore(timeout));
            webSessionIdResolver.ifAvailable(webSessionManager::setSessionIdResolver);
            return webSessionManager;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did below ended up working, but is obviously pretty hacky. I copied the definition of MaxIdleTimeInMemoryWebSessionStore into my own config class, and hardcoded the session timeout instead of reading from the properties file.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebFlux
public class MyApplication {    
    
    static final class MaxIdleTimeInMemoryWebSessionStore extends InMemoryWebSessionStore {

        private final Duration timeout;

        private MaxIdleTimeInMemoryWebSessionStore(Duration timeout) {
            this.timeout = timeout;
        }

        @Override
        public Mono<WebSession> createWebSession() {
            return super.createWebSession().doOnSuccess(this::setMaxIdleTime);
        }

        private void setMaxIdleTime(WebSession session) {
            session.setMaxIdleTime(this.timeout);
        }
    }
        
    @Bean
    public WebSessionManager webSessionManager(@Autowired WebSessionIdResolver webSessionIdResolver) {
        DefaultWebSessionManager webSessionManager = new DefaultWebSessionManager();
        Duration timeout = Duration.ofSeconds(10);
        webSessionManager.setSessionStore(new MaxIdleTimeInMemoryWebSessionStore(timeout));
        webSessionManager.setSessionIdResolver(webSessionIdResolver);
        return webSessionManager;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In application.yml you can adjust it. Here I set it to 36000 seconds.

```
server:
  reactive:
    session:
      timeout: 36000s
```